# How to group_by this array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, enumerable

I have read data in CSV format from a file into the following array:

```
arr = [
["company", "location", "region", "service", "price", "duration", "disabled"], 
["Google", "Berlin", "EU", "Design with HTML/CSS", "120", "30", "false"], ["Google", "San Francisco", "US", "Design with HTML/CSS", "120", "30", "false"], 
["Google", "San Francisco", "US", "Restful API design", "1500", "120", "false"],
["IBM", "San Francisco", "US", "Design with HTML/CSS", "120", "30", "true"],
["Google<script>alert('hi')<script>", "Berlin", "EU", "Practical TDD", "300", "60", "false"],
["Œoogle", "San Francisco", "US", "Restful API design", "1500", "120", "false"],
["Apple", "Berlin", "EU", "Practical TDD", "300", "60", "true"],
["Apple", "London", "EU", "Advanced AngularJS", "1200", "180", "false"],
["Apple", "New York", "US", "Restful API design", "1500", "120", "false"]
]
```

which i want to import in the database. Based on the below mentioned associations

```
# company.rb
  has_many :regions
  has_many :services

# region.rb
  has_many :branches
  belongs_to :company

# branch.rb
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :services

# service.rb
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :branch
```

May be the below mentioned hash can be used:(not sure. Please suggest a good design if possible)

```
{"Google" : [ 
  :name => "Google",
  :regions_attributes => {
    :name => "US", 
    :locations_attributes => {
      :name => "San Francisco"
    }
  },
  :services_attributes: [{
    :name => "Restful API design",
    ...
  },
  {
    :name => "Design with HTML/CSS",
    ...
  }]
]}
```

My attempt for this:

```
companies = []
CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
  company = {}
  company[:name]   = row['company']
  company[:regions_attributes] = {}
  company[:regions_attributes][:name] = row['region']
  company[:regions_attributes][:branches_attributes] = {}
  company[:regions_attributes][:branches_attributes][:name] = row['location']
  company[:services_attributes] = {}
  company[:services_attributes][:name] = row['service']
  company[:services_attributes][:price] = row['price']
  company[:services_attributes][:duration] = row['duration']
  company[:services_attributes][:disabled] = row['disabled']
  companies << company
end

companies.uniq! { |c| c.values }
companies = companies.group_by { |c| c[:name] }
```

It groups by company name.

I want to group services which are in one region as mentioned in the above example that Sanfrancisco, US has two services under it.

**Update**

Based on Cary Swoveland's solution, i'm able to modify as per the requirements but the associations are not working as i thought of.

```
companies = CSV.read(csv_file, headers: true).group_by {|csv| csv["company"]}
final = []
companies.transform_values do |arr1|
  company = Company.new(name: arr1.pluck("company").first.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options))
  services = arr1.map do |c|
    { name: c['service'], price: c['price'], duration: c['duration'], disabled: c['disabled'] }
  end.uniq
  company.services.build(services)
  regions = arr1.group_by { |csv| csv["region"] }.transform_values do |arr2|
    branches = []
    branches << arr2.pluck('location').uniq.map { |location| { name: location, services_attributes: services } }
    { name: arr2.pluck('region').uniq.first, branches_attributes: branches.flatten }
  end
  company.regions.build(regions.values)
  final << company
end

Company.import(final, recursive: true) #activerecord-import gem
```

Comment: Is ruby the Primary language? I can help in js

Comment: Can you provide the sample data as Ruby, not as a spreadsheet screenshot? Having a snippet of code we can use as a basis for experimentation is a **huge** help.

Comment: Uploading the file is a help, but the problem is that links tend to get broken and readers may see your question well into the future. The first step is to use `CSV.read` to read the file into an array. Right? It would be better to start with, "I have read data in CSV format from a file into the following array: `arr = [...]`. That way readers can just cut and paste. Be sure to include a variable name (e.g., `arr`) so readers can just reference it in answers and comments without having to define it. I suggest you delete the question, edit to make the changes and then undelete.

Comment: ...and make the array as small as possible (but still have all essential elements needed to illustrate solutions to the question, of course).

Comment: The string `"<script>alert('hi')<script>"` should be removed from `arr` (and, cosmetically, `arr[2]` should be on its own line). I don't fully understand the structure of hash you wish to return. You could clarify that by adding an element to `arr` for "Google"/"EU"/"London" and show the complete value of the key, `"Google"` in the hash to be produced from `arr`.

Comment: I'll update the question why i need the hash structure. Also i just realised the structure is a bit incomplete. May be after seeing the associations you can suggest a better design

Comment: I will. By 'complete value of the key, `"Google"`', I mean no `...` in that value; i.e, that value should be a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing the structure of your hash and constructing it with the code below. The file `'tmp.csv'` contains the first 20 or so rows of the csv file whose link is given by the OP. I've included its contents at the end.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.read('tmp.csv', headers: true).group_by { |csv| csv["company"] }.
    transform_values do |arr1|
      arr1.group_by { |csv| csv["region"] }.
           transform_values do |arr2|
             arr2.group_by { |csv| csv["location"] }.
                  transform_values do |arr2|
                    arr2.map { |csv| csv["service"] }.uniq
                  end
           end
    end
```

```
  #=> {"Google"=>{
         "EU"=>{
           "Berlin"=>["Design with HTML/CSS","Advanced AngularJS","Restful API design"],
           "London"=>["Restful API design"]
         },
         "US"=>{
            "San Francisco"=>["Design with HTML/CSS", "Restful API design"]
         }
       },
       "Apple"=>{
         "EU"=>{
           "London"=>["Design with HTML/CSS"],
           "Berlin"=>["Restful API design"]
         },
         "US"=>{
           "San Francisco"=>["Design with HTML/CSS"]
         }
       },
       "IBM"=>{
         "US"=>{
           "San Francisco"=>["Design with HTML/CSS"]
         },
         "EU"=>{
           "Berlin"=>["Restful API design"],
           "London"=>["Restful API design"]
         }
      }
     }
```

If this hash format is not suitable (but the content is what is needed), it could be easily changed to a different format.

See the docs for [CSV::read](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read), [CSV::Row#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D), [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

I was required to do some pre-processing on the linked csv file. The problem is that the company names were preceded by a "Byte Order Mark" for a UTF-8 file (Search for "Ok, figured it out" [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a89f06e6-b991-4724-aef0-56d5103f654b/hidden-characters-added-to-beginning-of-csv-when-exporting-report?forum=sqlreportingservices).) I used the code given [here] by Nathan Long to remove those characters. The OP will have to write the CSV files without those marks or strip them off when reading the files.

```
The content of my reduced CSV test file is the following.

arr = ["company,location,region,service,price,duration,disabled\n",
       "Google,Berlin,EU,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "Google,San Francisco,US,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "Google,San Francisco,US,Restful API design,1500,120,FALSE\n",
       "Apple,London,EU,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "Google,Berlin,EU,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "Apple,Berlin,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,FALSE\n",
       "IBM,San Francisco,US,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,TRUE\n",
       "Google,San Francisco,US,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "IBM,Berlin,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,TRUE\n",
       "IBM,London,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,TRUE\n",
       "IBM,Berlin,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,TRUE\n",
       "IBM,London,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,TRUE\n",
       "IBM,San Francisco,US,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,TRUE\n",
       "Google,Berlin,EU,Advanced AngularJS,1200,180,FALSE\n",
       "Google,Berlin,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,FALSE\n", 
       "Google,London,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,FALSE\n",
       "Apple,San Francisco,US,Design with HTML/CSS,120,30,FALSE\n",
       "Google,San Francisco,US,Restful API design,1500,120,FALSE\n",
       "IBM,Berlin,EU,Restful API design,1500,120,TRUE\n"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and i made the changes in the question. Also i need to stick with the format i mentioned in the question.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer to construct the hash in the desired format. First, however, I need a more complete understanding of the structure of the hash you wish to produce. See my new comment on the question.

Comment: You can now see the associations and update section as well for my progress

Comment: i have updated the associations. Please see the updated question

Comment: I'm still confused.  In the question you said, "Maybe the below-mentioned hash can be used:(not sure. Please suggest a good design if possible)". I suggested what I thought was a good design in my answer. You then commented, "Also i need to stick with the format I mentioned in the question" which seems contradictory. Also, the format you mentioned is not complete, so I really don't know what it is. That's why I suggested you add a row to `arr` for "Google/EU/London" and show what value you want for the key `"Google"` in the hash.

Comment: Actually i later realised that the association i thought of, were not perfect. So after working on them i asked to suggest a design of hashes based on associations. When i asked you to stick with the format was before the realisation. The whole confusion is because i later found out that the design i though will not work

Comment: Please see the update in the question. I have finally got the structure what i wanted but it is not working with the associations. Getting db `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:` as `DETAIL:  Key (name)=(EU) already exists.`. So may be i have redesign the associations.